# Accessing contents of an array within a dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I am attempting to access and retrieve values from an array I have stored as the Value data type in a dictionary but am not having any luck so far.  Please see the below example of my current syntax of my dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, double[]> dict= new Dictionary<string, double[]>();

double[] dubarray = new double[20];
String[] keyval = somestringarray[0].ToString();
```

I then have a loop that stores the keys/values to the dictionary.

```
dict.Add(keyval[0], dubarray);
```

Now I am parsing the dictionary and dependent upon the key access the values contained inside the array (dubarray).  I also want to return the entire array as well for logging purposes. Currently I getting returned the following: "System.Double[]"

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double[]> item in dict)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("dict.KEY is : " + item.Key + "dict.VALUE is : " + item.Value);
}
```

Can someone answer how I can access the data elements contained inside each instance of the dictionary?

Comment: The value *is* a `Double[]`, and that is what the default `ToString` will print for it. If you want to show all of the values, iterate over `item.Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join array values to write them:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double[]> item in dict)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("dict.KEY is : " + item.Key + 
                    "dict.VALUE is : " + String.Join(",", item.Value));
}
```

When you call `ToString()` on variable of array type you get just string containing type name - `"System.Double[]"` in your case.

Comment: Now although this allows me to print the values in the dictionary.  How would I go about calling to a specific value or index within that instance of the array?

Comment: @techietalk `item.Value` is `double[]` array. So, if you want to get first value, you can use `item.Value[0]`. But you need to be sure that array is not empty - otherwise you will get IndexOutOfRange exception

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] dubarray = dict[mystring].ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because ToString(), if not overwritten by the class, returns the fully qualified name of the type of Object. When you do

```
Debug.WriteLine(item.Value);
```

It automatically calls the ToString() function for the class in Value. In this case, it's an array of doubles, or System.double[].

What you want to do is get all of the values inside your array, string them together, and display that result.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double[]> item in dict)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("dict.KEY IS : {0}\ndict.VALUE is : {1}", 
                                   item.Key, string.Join(", ", meow["Test"])));
}
```

Comment: Now although this allows me to print the values in the dictionary.  How would I go about calling to a specific value or index within that instance of the array?